# Count number of replaces done with regex

Tags: regex, bash

I need to replace something in a number of files using regex. I do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find /path/to/dir \
    -type f \
    -name '*.txt' \
    -exec perl -e 's/replaceWhat/replaceWith/ig' -pi '{}' \; \
    -print \
    | awk '{count = count+1 }; END { print count " file(s) handled" }'

echo "Done!"
```

This code shows user the count of files it dealed with. But how could I count not files, but replaces? Every file handled could produce zero, one or many replaces with regex.

Comment: If you choose to write all your code in Perl, you can use the `(??{ code })`  syntax to increment the counter in the replacement. see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html

Answer (score 1):

You can add an extra `-exec` call to `grep`, then pass the number of matches to `awk` instead of just the filename:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

find /path/to/dir \
    -type f \
    -name '*.txt' \
    -exec grep -c 'replaceWhat' '{}' \; \
    -exec perl -e 's/replaceWhat/replaceWith/ig' -pi '{}' \; \
    | awk '{count += $0 }; END { print count " replacement(s) made" }'

echo "Done!"
```

Example (replacing "before" with "after"):

```
$ tail -n +1 *.txt
==> 1.txt <==
before
foo
bar

==> 2.txt <==
foo
bar
baz

==> 3.txt <==
before
foo
before
bar
before

$ ./count_replacements.sh
4 replacement(s) handled
$ tail -n +1 *.txt
==> 1.txt <==
after
foo
bar

==> 2.txt <==
foo
bar
baz

==> 3.txt <==
after
foo
after
bar
after
```